# how to get java bean value in servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, model-view-controller

```
AdminBean bean=new AdminBean();

        String uname=bean.getPass();
        String pass=bean.getPass();
        out.println(bean.getUname());
        out.println(bean.getPass());
```

printing null value

Answer (score 0):

You did not set value for your object, need set values for properties.

```
        AdminBean bean=new AdminBean();
        bean.setPass("123455");
        bean.setUname("ABC");
        String uname=bean.getPass();
        String pass=bean.getPass();
        out.println(bean.getUname());
        out.println(bean.getPass());
```

Comment: did you add ean.setPass("123455");
        bean.setUname("ABC");